# Why does this code crash at runtime? It is just a picker in a SwiftUI in a tabbed view

Tags: swift, swiftui, picker

Just a simple Tabbed App xcodeproj in SwiftUI.

Add a picker like this aaand: crash at runtime when switching to second tab.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var selection = 0
    @State private var pickerselection = 3
    let numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
    var aTitle: String = "Title"

    var body: some View {
        TabbedView(selection: $selection) {
// ADD ONLY THIS PART TO A NEW TABBED APP SWIFTUI PROJECT //// BEGIN /////
            VStack{

                Text("First View")
                    .font(.title)

                Picker(selection: $pickerselection, label:
                Text(aTitle)) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< numbers.count) { index in
                        Text(self.numbers[index]).tag(index)
                    }
                }
                }

////// XCODE 11.0 BETA 2 ONLY//////// END ////////////
            .tabItemLabel(Image("first"))
            .tag(0)

            Text("Second View")
                .font(.title)
                .tabItemLabel(Image("second"))
                .tag(1)
        }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

Compiles, but runtime crash when switching tabs:

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is hard to understand your code because it is not indented properly. If you fix it, it will be easier to help you. For example, the `Text("First View")` after the `VStack` should be indented further, and the closing brace for the `VStack` should be lined up with the `VStack`. Xcode can fix the indentation for you if you select the whole file and choose Editor > Structure > Re-Indent.

Comment: "Compiles". No it doesn't (not on my machine anyway).

Comment: Many times the xcode console will have very good clues about the crash. Depending on how you have breakpoints setup you man need to tap the button "continue program execution" before the console will give you the message you need.  Try that and then copy the console text here.

Comment: No console output this time, and no error dump. Weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem seems solved in XCode 11 beta 5.